# How to print my for loop just once? C#

Tags: c#, for-loop, methods, program-entry-point

```
internal class Invoice
{
    public static decimal[] Total =
        {
            InvoiceLineItem.quantity[0] * InvoiceLineItem.pricePerUnit[0],
            InvoiceLineItem.quantity[1] * InvoiceLineItem.pricePerUnit[1],
            InvoiceLineItem.quantity[2] * InvoiceLineItem.pricePerUnit[2],
            InvoiceLineItem.quantity[3] * InvoiceLineItem.pricePerUnit[3],
            InvoiceLineItem.quantity[4] * InvoiceLineItem.pricePerUnit[4],
            InvoiceLineItem.quantity[5] * InvoiceLineItem.pricePerUnit[5],
        };

    private decimal total1;
    private decimal total2;

    public void Customer1()
    {
        for (var i = 0; i < 3; i++)
            Console.WriteLine(String.Format("{0,-15} {1,-20} {2,-15} {3,-15} {4,-10}",
                InvoiceLineItem.productNumber[i],
                InvoiceLineItem.description[i],
                InvoiceLineItem.quantity[i],
                InvoiceLineItem.pricePerUnit[i],
                InvoiceLineItem.Total[i]));
    }

    public void Customer2()
    {
        for (var k = 3; k <= 5; k++)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(String.Format("{0,-15} {1,-20} {2,-15} {3,-15:C} {4,-10:C}",
                InvoiceLineItem.productNumber[k],
                InvoiceLineItem.description[k],
                InvoiceLineItem.quantity[k],
                InvoiceLineItem.pricePerUnit[k],
                Total[k]));
        }
    }

    public void Customer1Total()
    {
        for (var i = 0; i <= 2; i++)
        {
            total1 += Total[i];

            Console.WriteLine(String.Format("\nTotal of Customer 1:{0:C}", total1));
        }
    }
}
```

I'm having a hard time printing my for loop in method `Customer1Total()` just once. I need the output `total1` to only print once but it prints 3 times adding the totals incrementally. Basically I only need the last result of this for loop but I see all of the increments. Also for extra information I'm calling the method `customer1total` in my main for it to print.

Thank you.

Comment: just move `Console.WriteLine` outside loop

Answer (score 1):

```
public void Customer1Total()
{
    for(int i = 0; i <= 2; i++)
    {
        total1 += Invoice.Total[i];            
    }

    //Move write line outside the loop
    Console.WriteLine(String.Format("\nTotal of Customer 1:{0:C}", total1));
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Your `Console.WriteLine` statement is inside the loop body, move it after to have it execute after the loop has finished:

```
for(int i = 0; i <= 2; i++)
{
    total1 += Invoice.Total[i];
}
Console.WriteLine(String.Format("\nTotal of Customer 1:{0:C}", total1));
```

Also, be aware that because `total1` is a class level variable, its value will persist between calls to `Customer1Total()`, resulting in it increasing every time the function is called.